# jsfiddle explanation on Events

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I recently started learning JavaScript and I've been a frequent user of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) since then. Although it's pretty simple, I still have one problem understanding its events. ex: `no wrap (head)`, `onDomReady`

[image]

What are these events for and what are the differences between them? Can someone please do a decent explanation?

Thank you very much and happy new year!

Comment: -1 for cross posting. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127894/jsfiddle-explanation

Comment: @Oded I can't delete it because it has answers. Close it down if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dropdown specifies where jsFiddle should put your Javascript code in the generated HTML.

The first two options put it in a raw `<script>` block in the `<head>` or `<body>`.
The last two options put it in a Javascript event handler.

You can see how this works by [viewing the source of the generated page](http://jsfiddle.net/Ubfn6/).
(or [without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Ubfn6/1/))

Comment: I understand. The examples are pretty helpful. Thank you. :)